# ¿Como hacer referencia a un textView que esta en un Layout que no es el del setContentView()?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

UPDATE

Tengo 2 `layouts` que se cargan al mismo tiempo, en el 1er `layout` `activity_main.xml` tengo un `listView` y un `textView`, en el 2do `layout` `single_post.xml` tengo 4 `textView` que son los que se muestran en la `listView` del `activity_main.xml`

Quiero manipular el color del texto programaticamente de `single_post.xml`, intento acceder a el mediante `LayoutInflater` pero al parecer no funciona, con el código que tengo a continuación puedo hacer que cambie el color del texto del `textView` de `activity_main.xml` pero no logro hacer nada con el `textView` de `single_post.xml`

En el MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String sDesignation= "manager";

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_post, null);

        TextView estatus_SINGLE_POST=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_designation_SINGLE_POST);
        TextView estatus_ACTIVITY_MAIN=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_designation_ACTIVITY_MAIN);

            if(sDesignation.equals("manager")){
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YES "+sDesignation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   estatus_ACTIVITY_MAIN.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                   estatus_SINGLE_POST.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO "+sDesignation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                estatus_ACTIVITY_MAIN.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                estatus_SINGLE_POST.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
          }
        }
```

En el activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.user.testbd.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="manager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_designation_ACTIVITY_MAIN"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el single_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3">

    <TextView
        android:text="Name:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Designation:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_name"
        android:id="@+id/txt_designation_SINGLE_POST"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:text="name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es obtener el valor de un `textView` que se carga en otro `layout` pero solo puedo obtener el valor de los `textView` que se cargan en el `layout` que se indique en el método `setContentView();`

Answer (score 4):

Si no esta declarado dentro del layout que se carga a travez de [**setContentView()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) que en este caso es `activity_main.xml`, esto no es posible.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

La única opción es que dentro del archivo del layout exista una referencia a otro que lo contenga, esto se realiza mediante [**include**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

---

Por ejemplo supongamos que el `TextView` se encuentra dentro del archivo `otro_layout.xml` que esta indicado como [**include**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html), de esta forma si se puede obtener la referencia:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/otro_layout"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Creo que modificare mi pregunta porque utilizo los 2 layouts al mismo tiempo y no me explique bien

Comment: Si cargas atraves de setContentView solo puedes definir uno. Explica sobre como usas los 2 al mismo tiempo :)

Comment: Ya hice la actualización :)

Answer (score 3):

Si el `TextView` que quieres usar no se ha cargado en el contexto de la actividad mediante `setContentView()` debido a que está en otro layout, se puede cargar el otro layout de forma explícita y bastante sencilla, haciendo uso de [**LayoutInflater**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

```
// Instancia del servicio LayoutInflater
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// other.xml layout cargado (inflado) como View.
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null); 

// Obtiene una referencia al TextView del otro layout, other.xml
TextView tvOther = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvOther);
```

Ahora, podrás hacer un uso normal del `TextView`, como obtener su texto e incluso añadirlo al layout de la actividad actual haciendo uso de  `addView()`

Comment: oye amigo en la primer linea de código `activity` te refieres al archivo java o al archivo xml o a que?

Comment: @ElCóndor Es el archivo Java, la misma activity de la que has puesto el código en la pregunta. Ese `activity.` puede ser sustituido por un `this` o por nada, es simplemente para ponerte en contexto con la sentencia de código.

Comment: Con el nombre del archivo Java y con this me marcaba error si se lo quito no me marca error, lo probe y si me trae el valor que le doy por defecto el detalle aqui es que tiene un valor por defecto pero al momento de cargar el layout recibe un nuevo valor de una base de datos MySQL y ese valor no lo obtiene :/

Comment: Ya hice la actualización :)

Answer (score 1):

> La idea es obtener el valor de un textView que se carga en otro layout
>   pero solo puedo obtener el valor de los textView que se cargan en el
>   layout que se indique en el método setContentView();

Si quieres usar un texto que viene de otra Activity/Fragment/Etc con otro layout, deberás enviarle ese texto a la Activity dónde lo quieres usar como un extra en el intent.

Te pongo un ejemplo que usa un método estático para gestionar los extras de la Activity, hacerlo de esta manera es una buena práctica.

**Ejemplo:**

Primero necesitas el texto que lo obtienes cuando usas su layout.

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

Ahora necesitas enviar este texto a la Activity dónde quieres usarlo y no contiene ese textView en su layout.

```
startActivity(MyActivity.buildIntent(this, text));
```

Cuando arranque la Activity obtienes el texto del extra que has enviado.

```
    public static String EXTRA_TEXT = "extra_text";

    public static Intent buildIntent(Context context, String text){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            String text = bundle.getString(EXTRA_TEXT);
        }
    }
```

Aquí ya tienes en la variable 'String text' el texto que proviene de un TextView de otro layout que no usas en esta Activity

---

Por lo que veo estás cargando el segundo layout pero no lo añades a ninguna vista, de manera que no debería estar accesible aunque esté cargado.

Si no he entendido mal, deberías añadir todas las vistas que quieras ver, modificar, etc en el layout principal.

Prueba esto:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.user.testbd.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/other_layout" 
        layout="@layout/single_post"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/other_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="manager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_designation_ACTIVITY_MAIN"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Si quieres que el layout no sea visible añade visibility="gone". Y si quieres que sea visible pero aparezca en otro lado reestructura el layout activity_main.xml

Comment: El detalle o creo que no lo explique pero ambos layouts se usan al mismo tiempo, lo que pasa es que en el 1er layout `activity_main.xml` uso un listView y en el otro uso los `textView` hago esto porque la información la obtengo de una base de datos MySQL

Comment: Si están al mismo tiempo tienes acceso a ese textView en otro sitio, puedes cogerlo y enviarlo a la Activity que necesites. Igualmente creo que en tu caso te iría bien usar la librería Butterknife, es muy fácil de usar y seguramente podrás coger esa vista directamente desde la Activity que quieres sin que sea el layout del 'setContentView()'

Comment: Creo que modificare la pregunta con el código completo porque si hay una parte en donde obtengo el valor pero si en esa parte intento hacer un if me genera un error

Comment: Ya hice la actualización :)

Comment: Por favor @Marc usa la opción [editar] para modificar tu publicación actual. Así logramos centralizar el contenido en una sola respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal si solo lo declaras con sus métodos en una clase y luego solos los llamas desde clase principal.

ejemplo:

```
public String obtener valor(String s){
    TextView estatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_designation_single_post);

 s=estatus.getText().toString();

  return s;
}
```

Aun que claro en la clase que contiene los métodos declaras el layout correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Esa manipulación debés hacerla en el Adapter cuando agregás cada elemento al ListView. Seguramente en algún momento lo estés inflando y es ahí donde lo podés modificar, dentro del Adapter.

Si querés poné el código de tu Adapter y te oriento, pero aunque hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, podés revisar si tenés el método `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` en tu adapter. Ese método es el encargado de *crear* la vista que se mietra en cada item de la lista. Ahí podés modificar e ir a buscar cualquier elemento con el id.