# ¿Como concatenar una consulta MySQL con etiquetas html para enviarle el color al texto de un textView en Android?

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio, textview

El siguiente código en php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, concat('<div style="color:Red">',designation,'</div>') as designation FROM test.table_test;") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["designation"] = $row["designation"];

        $var_designation = $row["designation"];

    }
    echo "CON COLOR= ".$var_designation;
```

si lo ejecuto en un navegador me da como resultado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se lo mando a un textView me muestra literal esto:

```
<div style="color:Red">',designation,'</div>
```

Modifique la linea de la consulta MySQL por esto:

```
SELECT name, CONCAT('<font color="#FF0000">',designation,'</font>') as designation FROM test.table_test limit 1;
```

Pero me da el mismo resultado...

¿Sera posible lo que trato de hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más común me parece que sería almacenar el valor del color como Hexadecimal y de esta forma al obtenerlo se podría configurar el texto dentro del TextView:

```
String colorDB = "#00FF00";  //color verde.

textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorDB));
```

Si tienes esto en tu base de datos:

```
<font color="#FF0000">
```

Podrías realizar esto:

```
  String colorDB = "<font color="#FF0000">";  //color rojo
  String endFont = "</font>";
  String mensaje = "StackOverflow is cool!";

  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(colorDB 
+ mensaje + endFont));
```

Comment: Me marca error de sintaxis, creo que es en la parte donde abre el paréntesis `concat(\'`

Comment: @ElCóndor no había entendido tu pregunta, tu obtienes un color almacenado en una BD mediante una consulta, no veo necesario al macenar <font color="#FF0000">

Comment: De hecho no se encuentra almacenado sino que al momento de realizar la consulta lo concateno con CONCAT(); pero me diste una idea voy a almacenar el color en la base de datos para después concatenar pero creo que vuelvo al mismo problema de la pregunta que hice el otro día y aun no logro resolver  <http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52617/como-hacer-referencia-a-un-textview-que-esta-en-un-layout-que-no-es-el-del-setc> :(

Answer (score 1):

¿Porque asignarle el color en la consulta? Mejor haz una consulta común y corriente ya al momento de mostrar el valor ya le asignas el color, ejemplo:

```
$Color = "red";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, designation, as designation FROM test.table_test;") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["designation"] = $row["designation"];

        $var_designation = $row["designation"];

    }

 echo '<div style="Color:'.$Color.'">'.$var_designation.'</div>';
```

Entonces en Android recibes el valor y lo contienes en un `textview` el cual lo vas a personalizar dándole un color:

```
   holder.tuTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

**o**

```
tuTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("##DF0101"))
```

Comment: Lo voy a hacer así como me dices, el motivo de hacerlo así como lo publique es que el `textView` al que le quiero modificar el color de tu texto se encuentra en un 2do `layout`, eso lo publique en otra pregunta <http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52617/como-hacer-referencia-a-un-textview-que-esta-en-un-layout-que-no-es-el-del-setc> 1er `layout`=`listView`, 2do `layout`=`textvViews` ya intente usar `LayoutInflater` pero no he conseguido lo que me propongo y por ello se me ocurrió enviarle el color desde la consulta `MySQL`

Comment: tengo una duda que no se supone que al recibir el valor ya concatenado debe automáticamente verse reflejado el color que se concateno?