# Como puedo usar un string de un activity, en otra activity

Tags: java, android

Tengo un valor tipo String en mi clase `encuesta.java`, y quiero usar ese `String` en la clase `res8.java`, ambas son `Activity`.

Las dos clases se encuentran en el mismo paquete.

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pablo.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Resultados" />
    <activity android:name=".encuesta" />
    <activity android:name=".resProfesores" />
    <activity android:name=".res11" />
    <activity android:name=".res9" />
    <activity android:name=".res8"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

En el monitor de Android:

```
03-06 14:51:24.403 7172-7172/com.example.pablo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pablo.myapplication/com.example.pablo.myapplication.res8}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.pablo.myapplication.res8.onCreate(res8.java:20)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: Acceder a ellas, e imprimirlas, es decir mostrarlas en forma de string.

Comment: Importa la clase y accede a ella mediante el objeto instanciado. La variable debe estar declarada en la clase y no debe ser privada.

Comment: Como puedo importar la clase y acceder mediante objeto instanciado?

Comment: Tienes las clases en el mismo paquete o en diferentes paquetes?

Comment: En el mismo paquete.

Comment: Buenas, Pablo. Toda informacion relevante ha de añadirse a la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Deberias añadir la explicacion de tus clases, su UML por ejemplo. Un saludo.

Comment: @PabloGonzalez la opción común para enviar datos entre Activities es mediante un bundle que se envia en el Intent. Agregué respuesta. También como usar el valor y asignarlo a un TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Sería enviar enviar un dato tipo String entre Activities.

El envió de datos entre Actividades se realiza generalmente mediante un `Bundle` en el cual se agregan valores y ese `bundle` se envía a través de un `Intent` hacia la `Activity` destino.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(encuesta.this, res8.class);
    intent.putExtra("dato", "StackOverflow!");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Los valores se obtienen en la `Activity` destino mediante [getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()).

```
String datorecibido = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dato");
```

o simplemente:

```
String datorecibido = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
```

---

En la Activity que recibe el valor, puedes usar el valor y asignarlo a tu `TextView`:

```
String datorecibido = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dato");
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reslt); 
myTextView.setText(datorecibido);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo:

Esta línea en `encuesta.java`

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

Ahora necesitas enviar este texto a la otra Activity dónde quieres usarlo.
Esta línea en `encuesta.java`

```
startActivity(res8.buildIntent(this, text));
```

Cuando arranque la Activity obtienes el texto del extra que has enviado.
Este código en `res8.java`

```
public static String EXTRA_TEXT = "extra_text";

public static Intent buildIntent(Context context, String text){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        String text = bundle.getString(EXTRA_TEXT);
    }
}
```

From:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/52659/30953

---

En tu caso entiendo que coges el texto en `encuesta.java` y en algún momento quieres cambiar a la Activity `res8.java` y mantener el texto en la nueva Activity.

Deberías añadir el extra y el método `buildIntent()` a `res8.java` y utilizarlo desde `encuesta.java` dentro del `startActivity()`

Comment: No entiendo como poner el codigo, quiero pasar un String desde encuesta.java, a res8.java. Donde pongo cada codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu string es algo que tu defines, agrégala como recurso en el archivo strings.xml

```
<string name="cadena">Mi cadena</string>
```

Si es algo que ingresa el usuario, envíala como parámetro al crear la siguiente actividad

```
Intent intent = new Intent(encuesta.this, res8.class);
intent.putExtra("mi_cadena", miString);
startActivity(intent);
```

y lo recuperas en la siguiente actividad en el onCreate

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().hasExtra("mi_cadena")) {
    String miString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mi_cadena");
}
```

el if es para verificar si existe el valor, si no lo tiene ya podrías poner alguna sentencia que haga algo en caso de no enviar el dato

Comment: Hola, tengo este código en mi clase `res8.java`: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_res8);
        String nombre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("H");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, nombre, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}` Y en el `encuesta.java`, así: `Intent i = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
                    i.putExtra("H", nombre);
                    startActivity(i);` Y no me sirve, sale crash!

Comment: en el LogCat o Android monitor, ya viste donde esta fallando? puedes poner el log?

Comment: Ya puse el log en otra respuesta porque es muy largo.

Comment: Has declarado en el android manifest tu actividad?

Comment: No, como lo hago?

Comment: Muestra tu Android Manifest y te dire

Comment: Lo puse en otra respuesta porque es bastante largo.

Comment: Actualizare mi respuesta, intenta ese nuevo metodo