# Cargar datos a un spinner de un fragment en un dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, alertdialog, spinner

No he podido cargar los datos que tengo en un array(string) a un spinner que esta en un fragment el cual se muestra cuando toco un determinado botón.

Código de botón en la activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(R.layout.fragment_fragment_ventas);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("agregar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.show();
            builder.create();
```

Código Fragment

```
    Spinner spinner_productos;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_ventas, container, false);

    ArrayAdapter adapter_spinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.type_moned,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter_spinner.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_productos.setAdapter(adapter_spinner);

    return view;
}
```

Array en el archivo String

```
<array name="type_moned">
    <item>Moneda</item>
    <item>COP</item>
    <item>COP</item>
    <item>COP</item>
    <item>COP</item>
    <item>COP</item>
</array>
```

gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Yo he hecho eso dinámico, osea jalando toda la información de base de datos, solo aclárame esto:

1.Cargas un Fragment
2.El Fragment carga un DialogAlert customizado
3.El DialogAlert contiene un spinner?}.
Ese es tu flujo?

Comment: @GustavoTufiñoFernández 
estoy haciendo lo siguiente: 1. Cargo el Dialog 2.el Dialog contiene un Fragment 3. el Fragment tiene un spinner

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado creo que los mismo que esta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52617/como-hacer-referencia-a-un-textview-que-esta-en-un-layout-que-no-es-el-del-setc/52640#52640]